# Login authentication - null pointer exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm trying to validate user credentials using the following code, but I'm getting a null pointer exception every time the method is called:

```
public class LoginValidator {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static boolean validateUser(String email, String pswd){
        boolean status =  false;
        try{          
            EntityManager em;
            em =  emf.createEntityManager();
            Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Customer c where c.Email=:email and c.Password=:password")
                .setParameter("email", email)
                .setParameter("password", pswd);

            if (q.getResultList() != null)
                status = true;

            }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
            return status;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why this is happening?

Also, is this a good way to perform authentication? I'm not so sure about my use of `Query`

Comment: Where do you initialize `emf`?

Comment: Did you initialize `EntityManagerFactory emf`?

Comment: If it is more than a throw-away excercise, please consider hashing and salting the password.

Comment: The NullPointerException message will tell you exactly which line it occurs on, which is of great use. Probably where you try to use `emf` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emf is null, you have to initialize it:

```
private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistanceUnitName");
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't instantiated/injected the EntityManagerFactory emf.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Java EE application, as you indicate in the tags, use injection for the `EntityManager`:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

Do not use the EMF to instantiate the EM, it creates unnecessary overhead.

If it is more than a throw-away excercise, please consider hashing and salting the password, like this:

```
query.setParameter("password", computeSaltedHash(pswd));
```